# How to change OpenCV Mat dimensions with retaining previous data

Tags: android, opencv

I am writing a code utilizing OpenCV in Android. Now I want to change dimensions of a Mat object without rescale it (this is, retaining previous data). For example, a 4x4 mat:

```
0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0
```

change its size to 6x6

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I think that using copy operation would deteriorate performance, so what is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: I would just use `copyMakeBorder` to add a border of 2 on right and bottom. If this is slows things down too much, you'd better re-think about all your code, because this **can't** be the bottleneck of your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV Matrices are stored as a column-first single array, meaning that the memory of your first matrix actually looks like the following:

`[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]`

While the second matrix would look like this:

`[0 0 0 0` **0 0** `0 1 1 0` **0 0** `0 1 1 0` **0 0** `0 0 0 0` **0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0** `]`

Where the **bold** zeros are the new values. Meaning that to convert the first array into the second, you would not be able to directly use the first array, but would still have to copy each row separately. Therefore it does not really make it more efficient to keep the original array.

But in case you want to minimise the memory footprint, you can use `realloc` to change the size of allocated memory. I found it an interesting exercise, and created the following class that inherits the OpenCV Mat, and adds the `resize` function.

```
template <class T>
class ResizableMat : public cv::Mat_<T> {
public:
    // This only works when allocating dynamic memory up front
    ResizableMat(int rows, int cols) : cv::Mat_<T>(rows, cols, (T*)malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(T))) {;}
    ResizableMat(int rows, int cols, T initial) : cv::Mat_<T>(rows, cols, (T*)malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(T))) {
        std::fill((T*)this->data, ((T*)this->data) + rows * cols, initial);
    }

    ~ResizableMat() {
        if (this->data)
            free(this->data);
    }

    void resize(const size_t width, const size_t height) {
        assert(width > this->cols && "width must be bigger than original width");
        assert(height > this->rows && "height must be bigger than original height");
        const int newstep = width * sizeof(T);
        const size_t step_diff = newstep - this->step;
        this->data = (uchar *)realloc(this->data, width * height * sizeof(T));  // expand the memory
        for (int y = this->rows-1; y > 0; y--) {
            uchar *src = this->data + this->step * y;
            uchar *dst = this->data + newstep * y;
            memcpy(dst, src, this->step);               // copy the rows
            memset(&dst[this->step], 0, step_diff);     // fill the remainder of this row with 0
        }
        memset(&this->data[this->step], 0, step_diff);
        memset(&this->data[newstep * this->rows], 0, (newstep * height) - (newstep * this->rows));   // fill the remaining rows with 0
        this->step = newstep;
        this->rows = height;
        this->cols = width;
    }
};
```

This can be used like so:

```
ResizableMat<uchar> m(3,3, 1);
cout << "before:" << endl << m << endl;
m.resize(5, 5);
cout << "after:" << endl << m << endl;
```

Which outputs the following:

```
before:
[  1,   1,   1;
   1,   1,   1;
   1,   1,   1]
after:
[  1,   1,   1,   0,   0;
   1,   1,   1,   0,   0;
   1,   1,   1,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]
```

Numerous tests have shown that it is only slightly faster when operating on very large matrices and when the new size is only slightly bigger than the original. In all other scenarios it is slower, so therefore I can not recommend using this method over the standard.